# How to get a color depends on the percentage calculated

Tags: android, colors, percentage

I want to create a component with a color in it background , this color is variable from green to red ...
well I have a courses class with limit places for example 10 places = 100%,
students can join this class so for each student i need to calculate the percentage and using this percentage I change the color of the component until 100% and here the component will have Red color that's mean there is no other place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
private int getcolorPercentage(float percent) {

        return (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(percent, 0xff00ff00, 0xffff0000);
    }
```

Usage

```
int percent = 10;

view.setBackgroundColor(getcolorPercentage((float)percent/10‌​0));
```

Reference:

[android/animation/ArgbEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html)

Comment: Thank you it's work but you need to edit your answer 
view.setBackgroundColor(getcolorPercentage((float)percent/100));